# Does Directx11 support ASTC compressed textures?

Tags: directx, textures

I'm thinking of trying to use ASTC compressed textures for a multi-platform project, but haven't been able to find much documentation about whether DirectX11 supports them.  If DirectX11 supports ASTC textures what is best practice for loading them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[In the Microsoft documentation for ASTC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn914593(v=vs.85).aspx), it says right near the top:

> **Note**  ASTC is not available in the current release of the SDK.

Inspecting DXGI headers from the latest SDK, the ASTC formats in their documentation don't exist. From various press releases [eg this one](http://techarx.com/directx-12-and-direct3d-11-3-an-overview/), it seems as though ASTC was supposed to be in DirectX 11.3 (and 12), but doesn't seem to be available yet.

Comment: Even if it were it's not really supported by a lot of desktop hardware yet sadly.